# How to add a global right bar button (UINavigationController) in Three20's AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, three20

I want to add a global right bar button in the global AppDelegate so all my view controllers will have this button automatically.

I added in the AppDelegate

```
navigator.window.rootViewController.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem     
= [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Test", @"") 
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showTest)] autorelease];
```

Of course the above code is not working..any problem with the code above?

Comment: And, as far as I know, it is not possible to do this with the current state of the iPhone SDK. You need to add that item to each view controller you have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure you can do it in your way, because `UINavigatorController` always uses the buttons from the view controller that is currently displayed, and not from the top / root controller.

What you can do is to subclass `TTViewController` with a new view controller and set your left bar button item.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@implementation BaseViewController


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIViewController



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];


  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Test", @"") 
                                                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showTest)] autorelease];
}
```

and then you should extend all your view controllers from this base controller, which contains the right navigation bar item

Comment: Thanks. But as I have a UITabBarController which is always appear in the  app, why when I add the code into the viewDidLoad of my UITabBarController, the button cannot be shown?

Comment: Because the UITabBarController has no navigation bar. Only the UINavigationController does provide a navigation bar and therefore navigation bar buttons. even if you can place button items in the navigation bar in the interface builder. It is only a simulation and will not show in that way in your app.

compare:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 5):

What you need to do is to tap into the navigation controller you wish to hook into. then you can implement UINavigationControllerDelegate  (each navigation controller has a delegate property) which will give you these events:

```
// Called when the navigation controller shows a new top view controller via a push, pop or setting of the view controller stack.
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

You can implement

`- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;`

and put your right button in place.

Comment: This appears to be the best solution as it doesn't require subclassing, which is restrictive if you want to use a variety of UIView types.

Comment: I use these to update the navigationcontroller's viewcontrollers' styling upon changing the app theme. Very useful.

Comment: Do you mean to add the above code to every view controllers of the root navigation controller? I tried to add the code only to the class of the navigation controller but it did not work.

Comment: Where did you put these lines of code? In every view controller? @RupertRawnsley

Comment: @ChenyaZhang Implement a UINavigationControllerDelegate class and tell your UINavigationController about it using setDelegate. The code to actually add the buttons would then live in the willShowViewController method you created in your custom UINavigationControllerDelegate.

Comment: This solution is especially useful if you want to push SwiftUI Views in a UINavigationController