# Custom rightBarButtonItem disappearing

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, custom-controls, uinavigationbar, rightbarbuttonitem

I have a strange bug with a custom rightBarButtomItem in the NavBar. I have a TabBar application. If the app is loaded the button shows up correct. If i click through the tabs the button keeps showing. If i go back to one of the tabs which was already shown the button disappears. At the end the button only shows randomly in one of the tabs.

My code works perfectly if i set a standard rightBarButtomItem programatically. But not with custom graphics. If a ChildViewController is pushed and popped the button appears again. It seems it is still there but not visible!

I think my referencing of the sharedRightButton within the CustomTabBarViewController is wrong!

Can anybody help?

CustomTabBarController.h

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "EZBadgeView.h"

    @interface CustomTabBarController : UITabBarController
    {
        EZBadgeView *badgeView;
        UIButton *btn;
        UIImage *rightBarButtonItemImage;
        UIImage *rightBarButtonItemImageTapped;
        UIImage *rightBarButtonItemImageSelected;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *sharedRightButton;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) EZBadgeView *badgeView;
    @property(nonatomic, strong) UIButton *btn;
    @property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *rightBarButtonItemImage;
    @property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *rightBarButtonItemImageTapped;
    @property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage *rightBarButtonItemImageSelected;

    @end
```

CustomTabBarController.m

```
    #import "CustomTabBarController.h"

    @interface CustomTabBarController ()

    @end

    @implementation CustomTabBarController

    @synthesize sharedRightButton, badgeView, btn, rightBarButtonItemImage, rightBarButtonItemImageSelected, rightBarButtonItemImageTapped;

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateBadgeNumber:) name:@"updateBadgeNumber" object:nil];

        if (self.badgeView && self.badgeView.superview)
        {
            [self.badgeView removeFromSuperview];
        }
        self.badgeView = [[EZBadgeView alloc] init];
        CGRect badgeFrame = self.badgeView.frame;
        badgeFrame.origin.x = 31.0f;
        badgeFrame.origin.y = -6.0f;
        badgeFrame = CGRectIntegral(badgeFrame);
        self.badgeView.frame = badgeFrame;
        self.badgeView.badgeBackgroundColor = [self colorWithRGBHex:kRed withAlpha:1.0f];
        self.badgeView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.badgeView.badgeTextFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BrownStd-Bold" size:12];
        self.badgeView.shouldShowGradient = NO;
        self.badgeView.shouldShowShine = NO;

        // Allocate UIButton
        self.btn = [UIButton  buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        self.btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 46, 30);

        self.rightBarButtonItemImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_mixer.png"];
        [self.btn setBackgroundImage:rightBarButtonItemImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.rightBarButtonItemImageTapped = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_mixer_pressed.png"];
        [self.btn setBackgroundImage:rightBarButtonItemImageTapped forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        self.rightBarButtonItemImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_mixer_active.png"];
        [self.btn setBackgroundImage:rightBarButtonItemImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        [self.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(clickedTest:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [self.btn addSubview:self.badgeView]; //Add NKNumberBadgeView as a subview on UIButton

        // Initialize UIBarbuttonitem...
         self.sharedRightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
         self.badgeView.badgeValue = @"0";
         self.badgeView.hidden = YES;
    }

    - (void)updateBadgeNumber:(NSMutableArray *)soundArray
    {
        self.badgeView.badgeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[soundArray count]];
        self.badgeView.hidden = ([soundArray count] == 0);
    }

    - (void)clickedTest:(id)sender
    {
        NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (UIColor *)colorWithRGBHex:(UInt32)hex withAlpha:(float)alpha
    {
        int r = (hex >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int g = (hex >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int b = (hex) & 0xFF;

        return [UIColor colorWithRed:r / 255.0f
                               green:g / 255.0f
                                blue:b / 255.0f
                               alpha:alpha];
    }

    @end
```

And i set the button like that in each view:

```
@implementation MyVC

@synthesize tabBarController;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        //NSLog(@"begin: %s", __FUNCTION__);
        [super viewDidLoad];


         // right bar button from custom tabbarcontroller
        self.tabBarController = [[CustomTabBarController alloc] init];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.tabBarController.sharedRightButton;

}
```

Comment: Try to set the button in ViewWillAppear or ViewDidAppear

Comment: That was the first that i tried. That didn´t work too. It seems there is an issue with the TabBarController. But i don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It strikes me that creating a new `CustomTabBarController` for every view controller is fundamentally wrong, especially if it's to solve the problem that your right button isn't appearing. The issue is that you're creating new, phantom tab bar controllers, and worse, losing the reference to the view controller's real tab bar controller.

Your solution gets to the kernel of the problem, which is that, because you're adding subviews for your button, namely creating the `UIBarButtonItem` with `initWithCustomView`, etc., that you cannot share the button with multiple navigation controllers. The shared, common right bar button works if you create a simple `UIBarButtonItem` with `initWithTitle` (or other simple variations like that), but it doesn't work if you do it with a custom view for your button.

The right solution is to create a new `UIBarButtonItem` instance that has the behavior and appearance that you need. Then, any view controller that needs that bar button item can create an instance of that button. Thus, the new custom `RightBarButtonItem` might look like:

RightBarButtonItem.h:

```
@interface RightBarButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem

- (id)initWithTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action;

@end
```

RightBarButtonItem.m:

```
@interface RightBarButtonItem ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) EZBadgeView *badgeView;
@end

@implementation RightBarButtonItem

- (id)initWithTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 46, 30);

    self = [super initWithCustomView:button];

    if (self)
    {
        _badgeView = [[EZBadgeView alloc] init];
        CGRect badgeFrame = self.badgeView.frame;
        badgeFrame.origin.x = 31.0f;
        badgeFrame.origin.y = -6.0f;
        badgeFrame = CGRectIntegral(badgeFrame);
        _badgeView.frame = badgeFrame;
        _badgeView.badgeBackgroundColor = [self colorWithRGBHex:kRed withAlpha:1.0f];
        _badgeView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        _badgeView.badgeTextFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BrownStd-Bold" size:12];
        _badgeView.shouldShowGradient = NO;
        _badgeView.shouldShowShine = NO;

        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_mixer.png"]         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_mixer_pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_mixer_active.png"]  forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        [button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [button addSubview:_badgeView]; //Add NKNumberBadgeView as a subview on UIButton

        _badgeView.badgeValue = @"0";
        _badgeView.hidden = YES;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(updateBadgeNumber:)
                                                     name:@"updateBadgeNumber"
                                                   object:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    // don't forget to have mechanism to remove the observer when this button is deallocated

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:@"updateBadgeNumber"
                                                  object:nil];
}

- (void)updateBadgeNumber:(NSMutableArray *)soundArray
{
    self.badgeView.badgeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[soundArray count]];
    self.badgeView.hidden = ([soundArray count] == 0);
}

- (UIColor *)colorWithRGBHex:(UInt32)hex withAlpha:(float)alpha
{
    int r = (hex >> 16) & 0xFF;
    int g = (hex >> 8) & 0xFF;
    int b = (hex) & 0xFF;

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:r / 255.0f
                           green:g / 255.0f
                            blue:b / 255.0f
                           alpha:alpha];
}

@end
```

Then, the `CustomTabBarController` is greatly simplified:

CustomTabBarController.h:

```
@interface CustomTabBarController : UITabBarController

- (UIBarButtonItem *)rightBarButton;

@end
```

CustomTabBarController.m:

```
#import "RightBarButtonItem.h"

@implementation CustomTabBarController

- (UIBarButtonItem *)rightBarButton
{
    return [[RightBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                               action:@selector(clickedTest:)];
}

- (void)clickedTest:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

@end
```

And, finally, all of the view controllers that are added to the tab bar controller, can simply do:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CustomTabBarController *tabBarController = (id)self.tabBarController;

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [tabBarController rightBarButton];
}
```

All of this achieves the critical part of your proposed solution, namely to ensure that we have a unique instance of the right bar button item, but without the problem of creating redundant tab bar controllers.

Comment: i´ve changed my code now and it works perfectly! thank you very much again!!! one question i have as i see your code is much cleaner than mine: you put the interface and the property definition in the implementation file. I´ve seen that before but was not sure what difference it makes. Another thing is using the property with uderscore like _badgeView vs. badgeView. I´ve seen that before too but don`t understand it. Could you please provide me a link where it is explained?

Comment: @rockstarberlin - The idea behind putting some property definitions in the .m file (in what's called a "private class extension") is to restrict the .h file to those public interfaces that are needed by other classes and keep all the gory details of the private implementation in the .m file. It's functionally the same (as far as the .m file goes), but it's cleaner and less confusing when you go to use the class at some future date. I also noticed that you had some properties that you only needed during initialization, so I just made those local variables (or got rid of the variable entirely).

Comment: @rockstarberlin Re the _ variables, the subtle issue is that you shouldn't use accessor methods (the `self.` prefix) in initializer methods. See [Practical Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html).