# How do I change the rightbarbuttonitem from appdelegate?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

How do I change the right bar button item of my current view controller from the appdelegate file?

thanks.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the structure of your app. Why do you want to change it from the app delegate rather than from the controller where you want this right bar button item to appear?

Answer (score 1):

The `appDelegate` pretty much should handle that responsibility to the view controller that he will instantiate and shall be shown in the keyWindow. And that responsibility then will be handled from the `UINavigationController` to its currently showing `UIViewController` subclass on the top of the navigation stack.

TL;DR: AppDelegate doesn't understand no puny `rightBarButtonItem`, puny right button is for navigation items.

If you want a solution to always have a consistent right bar button, you can take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388566/how-to-add-a-global-right-bar-button-uinavigationcontroller-in-three20s-appde).